# Condtional match columns across different dataframes

Tags: r, string-matching

I'm working with two datasets - one set has pairs of items:

```
original <- data.frame(label1 = c("cat", "cat", "dog", "dog", "cat", "tiger", "tiger", "cow"),
                      label2 = c("dog", "dog", "cat", "cat", "dog", "cow", "cow", "tiger"))
original
  label1 label2
1    cat    dog
2    cat    dog
3    dog    cat
4    dog    cat
5    cat    dog
6  tiger    cow
7  tiger    cow
8    cow  tiger
```

the second dataset contains index codes for items from the first set:

```
index <- data.frame(item = c("cat", "dog", "tiger", "cow"),
                    code = c(1, 0, 1, 0))
index
   item code
1   cat    1
2   dog    0
3 tiger    1
4   cow    0
```

I'm looking for a way to create two new columns: `tag0` and `tag1` so that it looks like this:

```
new <- data.frame(label1 = c("cat", "cat", "dog", "dog", "cat", "tiger", "tiger", "cow"),
                  label2 = c("dog", "dog", "cat", "cat", "dog", "cow", "cow", "tiger"),
                  tag1 = c("cat", "cat", "cat", "cat", "cat", "tiger", "tiger", "tiger"),
                  tag0 = c("dog", "dog", "dog", "dog", "dog", "cow", "cow", "cow"))
new
  label1 label2  tag1 tag0
1    cat    dog   cat  dog
2    cat    dog   cat  dog
3    dog    cat   cat  dog
4    dog    cat   cat  dog
5    cat    dog   cat  dog
6  tiger    cow tiger  cow
7  tiger    cow tiger  cow
8    cow  tiger tiger  cow
```

`tag0` refers to the label corresponding to `code=0` and `tag1` refers to the label corresponding to `code=1` in the `index` dataframe.

Could anyone help me out with a `tidyverse` based solution?

Comment: This `index` schema is a bit strange. What is the logic mapping {`label1`, `label2`} to (`tag1`, `tag0`)?  My guess is that {`cat`, `dog`} is treated identically to {`dog`, `cat`} regardless of order, where `cat` and `dog` are always paired together; and likewise for `tiger` and `cow`.  But that isn't made clear in the question...

Comment: the `index` contains a list of all unique labels from `original` stored as `item` with a `code` value. While items (dog or cat) might appear in `label1` or `label2` within one row with equal probability, the `tag` refers to their `code` value.

Comment: OK, so `index` is derived from `original`?

Comment: yes. `index` lists all unique values present in either `label1` or `label2` in `original`

Comment: And so the `code` is assigned arbitrarily?  Or is the `code` (`1` or `0`) based on the order (left or right) in which the words first appeared in `original`?

Comment: `code` is predefined and fixed - in my real dataset it codes positive vs negative traits

Comment: Thanks for accepting my answer!  I just updated my answer with an extra solution, which has a more elegant workflow and is more flexible.

Comment: Let me know if the new solution works for you, so I can overwrite the original and clean up my post.  I don't want to overwrite it until I know it works on your end; otherwise I'd be leaving an ineffective "solution" in an "accepted" state.

Comment: they both work, thank you. While I understand steps from solution 1, I need to do some reading on `c_across` from solution 2.

Comment: Basically, [`c_across`](https://rdrr.io/cran/dplyr/man/c_across.html) `(label1 | label2)` gets you `c("cat", "dog")` from row `1`, `c("cow", "tiger")` from row `8`, and so forth; when used in tandem with `rowwise()`.  This let us check if the `item` matches one of the labels in that row.  Specifically, it lets us do so for all `label*` columns matching the regex `label\d+`.

Comment: **However** if you tried `c(label1 | label2)`, you'd get a long vector that is essentially the `label1` column stacked upon the `label2` column: `c(c("cat", "cat", "dog", ..., "tiger", "cow"), c("dog", "dog", "cat", ..., "cow", "tiger"))`.  Naturally, this is useless for comparison within each row.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here are two solutions in the [**`tidyverse`**](https://www.tidyverse.org/). While the first works for this particular case, I favor the second, which is more elegant and extensible.

## Solution 1: A `JOIN` for Each `label*`

First import the `tidyverse` and generate your datasets `original` and `index`.

```
library(tidyverse)


# ...
# Code to generate 'original' and 'index' datasets.
# ...
```

Then apply this workflow.

```
original %>%
  # Uniquely identify each row (for pivoting later).
  mutate(row_id = row_number()) %>%
  # Match 'label1' to the tags.
  left_join(
    index,
    by = c("label1" = "item"),
    keep = TRUE
  ) %>%
  # Match 'label2' to the tags.
  left_join(
    index,
    by = c("label2" = "item"),
    keep = TRUE,
    suffix = c(".1", ".2")
  ) %>%
  # Pivot 'item.1 | ... | item.n | code.1 | ... | code.n' into a consolidated
  # 'item | code' form.
  pivot_longer(
    cols = matches("^(item|code)\\.(\\d+)?$"),
    names_pattern = "^(item|code)\\.(\\d+)?$",
    names_to = c(".value", NA)
  ) %>%
  # Pivot back into a 'tag1 | tag0' form.
  pivot_wider(
    values_from = item,
    names_from = code,
    names_glue = "tag{code}"
  ) %>%
  # Omit unique identifier.
  select(!row_id)
```

### Result

Given the `original` and `index` datasets like those reproduced here

```
original <- data.frame(
  label1 = c("cat", "cat", "dog", "dog", "cat", "tiger", "tiger", "cow"),
  label2 = c("dog", "dog", "cat", "cat", "dog", "cow", "cow", "tiger")
)

index <- data.frame(
  item = c("cat", "dog", "tiger", "cow"),
  code = c(1, 0, 1, 0)
)
```

this solution should yield the following result:

```
# A tibble: 8 x 4
  label1 label2 tag1  tag0 
  <chr>  <chr>  <chr> <chr>
1 cat    dog    cat   dog  
2 cat    dog    cat   dog  
3 dog    cat    cat   dog  
4 dog    cat    cat   dog  
5 cat    dog    cat   dog  
6 tiger  cow    tiger cow  
7 tiger  cow    tiger cow  
8 cow    tiger  tiger cow
```

### Note

If your `original` dataset has any further `label*` columns, you'll need to perform an extra `JOIN` for *each and every one* of those columns.

---

## Solution 2: A Single `CROSS JOIN`

Here's a **more elegant workflow**, which is also **more flexible**: it works for an arbitrary number of `label*` columns in `original` and an arbitrary set of `code`s in `index`.

```
original %>%
  # Uniquely identify each row (for pivoting later).
  mutate(row_id = row_number()) %>%
  # Perform a cross-join compare every 'item' to every 'label*'.
  full_join(
    index,
    by = character()
  ) %>%
  # Keep only those rows where 'item' matches a 'label*'.
  rowwise() %>%
  filter(item %in% c_across(matches("^label\\d+"))) %>%
  # Pivot into a 'tag1 | tag0' form.
  pivot_wider(
    values_from = item,
    names_from = code,
    names_glue = "tag{code}"
  ) %>%
  # Omit unique identifier.
  select(!row_id)
```

### Result

The results remain identical.

```
# A tibble: 8 x 4
  label1 label2 tag1  tag0 
  <chr>  <chr>  <chr> <chr>
1 cat    dog    cat   dog  
2 cat    dog    cat   dog  
3 dog    cat    cat   dog  
4 dog    cat    cat   dog  
5 cat    dog    cat   dog  
6 tiger  cow    tiger cow  
7 tiger  cow    tiger cow  
8 cow    tiger  tiger cow
```

### Note

The only drawback is that it must perform a **`CROSS JOIN`**, which could hinder performance on larger datasets.

Answer (score 1):

Another possible solution:

```r
library(tidyverse)

original <- data.frame(label1 = c("cat", "cat", "dog", "dog", "cat", "tiger", "tiger", "cow"),
                       label2 = c("dog", "dog", "cat", "cat", "dog", "cow", "cow", "tiger"))

index <- data.frame(item = c("cat", "dog", "tiger", "cow"),
                    code = c(1, 0, 1, 0))

original %>% 
  full_join(index, by=c("label1" = "item")) %>% 
  full_join(index, by=c("label2" = "item")) %>% 
  mutate(tag1 = if_else(code.x == 1, label1, label2)) %>% 
  mutate(tag2 = if_else(code.y == 1, label1, label2)) %>% 
  select(!starts_with("code"))

#>   label1 label2  tag1 tag2
#> 1    cat    dog   cat  dog
#> 2    cat    dog   cat  dog
#> 3    dog    cat   cat  dog
#> 4    dog    cat   cat  dog
#> 5    cat    dog   cat  dog
#> 6  tiger    cow tiger  cow
#> 7  tiger    cow tiger  cow
#> 8    cow  tiger tiger  cow
```